# Use of hyphen in shell command

Tags: command-line-interface, shell

I feel shy to ask this question, but if I don't I will never know, so here I am giving it a shot:

I notice most shell commands use "-" for options, but I also noticed some commands do not have it. For example, to archive files in a given direct, the command is:

```
tar czvf allmyfiles.tar.gz *
```

However, to extract an archive, the command I learned, is:

```
tar -zxvf allmyfiles.tar.gz
```

Looking at both examples above, is there any significance whether to include the hyphen or not?

Comment: tar -czvf allmyfiles.tar.gz * will work too

Answer (score 2):

Most modern programs use [getopt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt) for parsing their arguments:

> ... the original authors picked out of the variations support for single character options, multiple options specified together, and options with arguments (-a arg or -aarg), all controllable by an option string.

But as always, there are some programs which do things their own way regardless (`dd` is a good example).

**Update**: BSD programs tend to use options without hyphens - for example, the manpage of [`ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) states:

> This version of ps accepts several kinds of options:
>
> 1. UNIX options, which may be grouped and must be preceded by a dash.
> 2. BSD options, which may be grouped and must not be used with a dash.
> 3. GNU long options, which are preceded by two dashes.

Answer (score 2):

The commands 'tar' and 'ar' are very, very old and pre-date the convention using dashes.

Comment: On a related note, for some programs options used to be prefixed by `+` as well. `dig` for example.

Answer (score 0):

With `tar`, it (usually) makes no difference. There is no rule to say whether or not all commands will follow this convention or not, but the general guideline is `command -arguments`.

Comment: In tar there is a difference. When using old-style option (without -) you have to give all options first and after that all the arguments. When using short-style (with -) all arguments have to follow their associated options.

So "tar czfv allmyfiles.tar.gz *" creates the archive "allmyfiles.tar.gz" but "tar -czfv allmyfiles.tar.gz *" creates the archive "v" (and gives an error if allmyfiles.tar.gz doesn't exist, as it is to be included into v).